# Can this really check the last day of the month in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

I want to check if the current day is the last day of the month irrespective of the number of days in that current month. Every last day of that current month do something

I mean if its 28 Feb 2021 do something.

My code

```
 var lastDayOfTheCurrentMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth) == 1;

                        if (lastDayOfTheCurrentMonth)
                        {
                            //calculate interest
                        }
                        {
                            //else return
                        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Add one day to a date. If the resulting day of the new date is 1, the old date was the last day of the month.

Comment: @sr28 I tested it, only the else block for read.

Comment: @mjwills I dont understand what you mean. You mean ```if (lastDayOfTheCurrentMonth + 1)```

Comment: He means `if (date.AddDays(1).Day == 1)` (So if you want to check today, do `if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day == 1)`)

Comment: Thanks everyone, All the suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it slightly easier to read and do this:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var isLastDayOfMonth = (today.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));

if(isLastDayOfMonth)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

You can test this in a console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var isLastDayOfMonth = (today.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));

        Console.WriteLine("Is Last Day: " + isLastDayOfMonth);

        var lastDay = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31);
        isLastDayOfMonth = (lastDay.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(lastDay.Year, lastDay.Month));

        Console.WriteLine("Is Last Day: " + isLastDayOfMonth);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Results:

[image]

If you're likely to use this more than once you can create an extension method as per Johnathan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static bool IsLastDayInMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
    return DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month) == dt.Day;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (DateTime.Today.IsLastDayInMonth())
{

}
```

`DateTime.Day` returns the day of the month, which is compared to the number of days in that month.

Answer (score -1):

Yes!  I drew up this .NET Fiddle to showcase:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kPTL90

I don't really understand what you're trying to do in your code, the expression `DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth)` will generally evaluate to 30 or 31 (or 28/29 in the case of February).  Why are you then comparing it to 1?

Comment: I didn't downvote but: you only link to code (you don't show it in your answer) and you only print the last day of the month, you don't compare ("*is* this date on the last day?")